# Convert varchar column to smalldatetime

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, varchar, smalldatetime

I have a table with 800+ records. In this table I have a column named 'Data' of varchar(10) datatype which contains dates in *dd.MM.yyyy* format.I want to convert it to smalldatetime.

I've tried converting it using Enterprise Management Studio Express, but I receive this error:

`The conversion of char data type to smalldatetime data type resulted in an out-of-range smalldatetime value.`

How can I convert it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll need to do a little string manipulation to get this to work as I think SQL is expecting 'MM.dd.yyyy'. So, update your table to flip-flop the month and day first, then the conversion should go through.

```
update YourTable
    set Data = SUBSTRING(Data,4,3) + LEFT(Data,3) + RIGHT(Data,4)
```

Comment: WELL NOTED      OKAY

Answer (score 0):

You can use:
`SELECT  ID, CAST(VarcharCol As SmallDateTime) as DateTimeCol From Test1`
This will return a table with varcharcol values as smalldatetime
Then update the content of varcharcol with the new values.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want implicit conversion to *smalldatetime*, you should use [CONVERT and the argument *style*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#date-and-time-styles).
*dd.MM.yyyy* format correspond to style *104*.
For example :

```
SELECT CONVERT(smalldatetime, '31.12.2018', 104) AS "Result"

Result
------
2018-12-31 00:00:00
```